# EOS premium name bidding / refunding / alert tools (eosio.names)

Tags: account-name

As I am exploring the premium EOS name bidding stuff, I noticed that if someone outbids another previous bidder, EOS automatically issues a refund transaction to return the staked bids. That's great. But this is happening any time of the 24/7 cycle so if someone really wants a name, they would have to put a ton of EOS on staking else someone can outbid them overnight without any alerts.

Anyone aware of any tools that can alert when an outbid situation happens. I am already trying to write one for myself but thought I ask here. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hack it, GenerEOS has a site that tracks bidding:

https://toolkit.genereos.io/names

They've also posted their source code:

https://github.com/genereos/eostoolkit